# Can nmap undergoing host scan slow my internet speed?

Tags: network, nmap, performance

I've been scanning my network for new hosts using this command:

```
nmap -v -sn 192.168.0.0/16 10.0.0.0/8
```

I have a lot of users in my network. Does the nmap scan slow down my network traffic or do I just have a load due to users?

Comment: Why are you scanning the class a and  b subnets together like this? Are you not using a class c network?

Comment: I have access to another network with a different subnet  that's why

Comment: That does not make sense. What is your primary LAN setup? For host discovery you need to map out each LAN. If you are using class a and b for internal networking it suggests you have hundreds of thousands of users.

Comment: actually its type of a classification, where  DMZ  servers has a separate subnet and my user's subnet and a router in between

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nmap will be performing a ping scan in chunks of 4096 host addresses at, at least, 2 ports per host address, (corrected thanks to @Trickycm), it will be generating quite a lot of traffic so **yes** it will be impacting your other network traffic to some degree but depending on the number of pings and the rate pinged at I would expect the impact to be moderate.

You can add options to reduce the impact:

```
  --max-retries <tries>: Caps number of port scan probe retransmissions.
  --host-timeout <time>: Give up on target after this long
  --scan-delay/--max-scan-delay <time>: Adjust delay between probes
  --min-rate <number>: Send packets no slower than <number> per second
  --max-rate <number>: Send packets no faster than <number> per second
```

Comment: Where are you getting the 4096 from? Also -sn will send at least 4 probes.

Comment: @Trickycm on my Windows 10 machine running `nmap -vvvv -sn  --unprivileged 192.168.0.0/16 10.0.0.0/8` tells me: `Scanning 4096 hosts [2 ports/host]`

Comment: 4096 is the number of hosts in the two subnets,,

Comment: @Steve Barnes nmap will split the scan in to chunks if it is massive. In your case 4096 chunks. This scan though is a full class a and b so 65000+ hosts. If ran your scan it would up update after each 4096 block. Also the 2 probes is technically correct, but it also sends 2 ICMP requests.

Comment: @mrashid that would mean nmap already knows the number of hosts before the scan...

Comment: @Trickycm yes nmap calculate the number of hosts it will scan based on subnets you provided

Comment: @mrashid, that is just wrong. https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html

Comment: @Trickycm - answer edited thank-you for the clarification.

Comment: @mrashid 10.0.0.0/8 will scan 16777214 hosts and 192.168.0.0/16 65534 more so lots https://www.pantz.org/software/tcpip/subnetchart.html for more.

Comment: oooh, that's right thanks for making that clear @Trickycm